# Same query producing 2 different results

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query that I am running on 2 different servers, a development and production server.

```
SELECT TeacherID, COUNT(StudentID) AS Students
FROM TeacherStudentRecord tsr
JOIN TeachersApplicationRecord tar 
ON tsr.TeacherID = tar.TeacherID
WHERE Semester = 1
AND Semester1 = 1
AND Semester1T= 0
AND Year = 2016
GROUP BY TeacherID
HAVING COUNT(StudentID) = (
    SELECT MIN(COUNT)
    FROM (
                SELECT COUNT(tsr.StudentID) as COUNT
                FROM TeacherStudentRecord tsr
                JOIN TeachersApplicationRecord tar 
                ON tar.TeacherID = tsr.TeacherID
                WHERE Semester = 1
                AND Year = 2016
                GROUP BY TeacherID) 
    AS T)
```

Both servers have the same tables with the same data. When I run the query on development server, I get the response I expect. When I run it on production, I get "MySQL returned an empty result set".

The only difference AKAIK between the two servers is the version of pma. The dev server is running pma 4.1.12 and the prod server is running pma 3.5.2.2. Do the different versions of pma interpret SQL differently? Or is there something else in my query that is causing this issue?

Comment: did you try running your subquery alone whether your subquery is returning the result as expected?

Comment: @TajAhmed Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried the subquery on its own on both servers and they are returning the same results.

Comment: are you sure this is the exact query which is running? because it should have table alias prefixes in where clause if it is.

Comment: Any chance that it's actually showing you the results and just not displaying the proper count? There had been some issues with subqueries and result counts. Also, version 3.5 is quite old and not supported anymore, you should consider upgrading.